# Silverlight MEF ExportFactory<T> call to Dispose Does not Dispose

Tags: silverlight, prism, mef

Having problem with memory leaks with NonShared objects in a Silverlight 5 application using Prism and MEF so have attempted to use ExportFactory< T > to create my ViewModels which is supposed to be a solution from what I've read.  However, calling Dispose on the ExportLifetimeContext doesn't remove the objects from memory either.  The following code creates an instance of DataEntryViewModel, but the call to dispose of the ExportLifetimeContext two lines later, has no effect. Any suggestions?

```
[Export("DataEntry", typeof(UserControl)), PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public partial class DataEntry
{
    private readonly ExportFactory<DataEntryViewModel> _ExportFactory;
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public DataEntry(ExportFactory<DataEntryViewModel> exportFactory)
    {
        _ExportFactory = exportFactory;
        var context = _ExportFactory.CreateExport();
        DataContext = context.Value;
        context.Dispose();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dispose does not remove objects from memory. That's the Garbage Collector's job. Following the dispose pattern you can release unmanaged resources.

What you are doing in the following section will lead to problems:

```
var context = _ExportFactory.CreateExport();
DataContext = context.Value;
context.Dispose();
```

because you are disposing `context` but you keep a reference to `context.Value` on `DataContext`.

In the documentation of [ExportLifetimeContext.Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382762%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is it remarked that:

> Call Dispose when you are finished using the ExportLifetimeContext.
>   The Dispose method leaves the ExportLifetimeContext in an unusable
>   state. After calling Dispose, you must release all references to the
>   ExportLifetimeContext so the garbage collector can reclaim the
>   memory that the ExportLifetimeContext was occupying.

What you can do is override [Component.Dispose(bool)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9yzd5cx.aspx) in the DataEntry class and call `context.Dispose` in there. So when the `UserControl` is disposed, the `ExportLifetimeContext` will also get disposed.